# Facebook comments screams "unreachable" after 301-redirect

Tags: facebook, redirect, comments

I recently moved an old link on my site to a new URL but I've kept the Facebook comments link to the old one on my site because it had many comments on it. When someone tries to access `/old-link` on their browser, they get 301'd to `/new-link`. But since my fb comments are pointing to `/old-link` Facebook screams with a yellow warning above the comments box that says:

```
Warning: http://example.com/page.html is unreachable.
```

When I click the link, the debugger shows everything without any errors. It resolves to `/new-link` and displays the data from there.

What can I do to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by clicking on the URL, which took me to the debugger, and refreshing it a few times on the debugger. Then when I went back to the comments, facebook had updated the cache so the warning was gone. It's all perfect now.